# Initialize Array with shape

Tags: julia

I want a matrix not the same shape as another matrix, but with the shape the other matrix holds.

```
shape=[2,3]
matrix=zeros(shape)
size(matrix)=(2,)
```

How can I get `size(matrix)=shape`?

I could do it like this:

```
matrix=zeros(shape[1],shape[2])
```

is there a more generic way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `zeros(shape...)`. The splat operator `...` turns a vector into parameters for a function:

```
v = [a,b,c]
func(v...)  # is the same as
func(a,b,c)
```

and it works for tuples too:

```
t = (a,b,c)
func(t...)  # is the same as
func(a,b,c)
```